# Call cms block in store language in Magento2

Tags: magento2.2, cms-block, multi-language

In Magento2, I have CMS a page on which I want to upload the customer registration form. I have inserted this code for it:

```
{{block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register" template="Magento_Customer::form/register_default_fr.phtml"}}
```

The website is in two different languages. Yet the block loads in the default language (English) on both store views.

Could anyone tell how to load the registration form in the corresponding store view languages?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you have a language translator csv file available for another language?

Comment: Where can I check it? It was not me who created the Skin. Thanks!

Comment: Please create two  CMS  pages with customer registration form and assign separate store views to those CMS pages.